# Set View Visibility GONE keep other views

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some xml that looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="34sp"/>
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call"
    android:id="@+id/callText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Text"
    />

 />
```

And now I want to set the TextView with the id `Text` to GONE, but when I do this the TextView with the id `callText` also disappears, what I want is to set `Text` to GONE and then just have `callText` move up, and stay visible?

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This might be because you're aligning it based on Text.

Comment: @Zar I know thats why its happening but, I want to keep that reference but not have it also disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` to use the parent as the anchor if the specified anchor is missing:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing

> If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the anchor cannot be be found for layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `callText` textView position depends on the Text `textView` position. The easiest way is to use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, but if you want to keep that layout you can either use `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` as suggested by ci_ or remove the position dependency.

Comment: I added `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` to the `callText`? and it didn't work? it still disapperaed

Answer (score 0):

Just use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`. Then you will be free to set the visibility of `Text` to `GONE` without clobbering the placement of `callText`.